# Ionic file plugin Error on creating directory on root internal storage

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have concern now when testing to create a directory inside the platform root Internal Memory:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FileError: {"code":12,"message":"PATH_EXISTS_ERR"}

I have this code for testing

```
copyFileToPictures(namePath, currentName, newFileName) {
    this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory,"LGU",false);
  }
```

Hope you can help me,

Thanks

Comment: Set android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in application tag  in AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work,

It seems problem for Android 10 devices

Comment: change the target SDK version on Android Studio.

Comment: Could you add that to your Answer, please?